# Where on my S3 can I find the punctuation button to type a "guillemets"?

Tags: keyboard

I want to type the French and German style "guillemets" marks (« or ») on my mobile.  Where on my keyboard is it?

OS: 4.1.1

Galaxy S3

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillemet

Answer (score 3):

<s>Apparently the stock keyboard does support it, as [wbogacz's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/48737/23562) shows. I was not aware of this, as I never used the stock keyboard.</s>

Evidently those aren't guillemets on the stock keyboard.

I do not believe the stock keyboard supports this.  You'll need to use an alternative keyboard to get this functionality.

Using an alternative keyboard is another way to get this functionality which is a bit easier to access.

One keyboard I know of that supports it is [Hacker's Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard), which is the keyboard I use myself.

To type « and » on that keyboard, you do a long press on the circle button (at the bottom-right.  It acts as the [compose key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key) in this context), release it, and then type << or >> respectively

To get ‹ and ›, you do the same and type .< or .>

An exhaustive list of all the supported compose key combinations can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/hackerskeyboard/source/browse/java/src/org/pocketworkstation/pckeyboard/ComposeSequence.java).

Comment: "To type « and » ←[how are you getting the different size ones?] on that keyboard, you do a long press on the circle button (at the bottom-right. It acts as the compose key in this context), release it, and then type << or >> ← [this set looks bigger] respectively"

Comment: @verve - The former are the actual guillemet characters, whereas the latter are just a pair of greater-than/less-than signs.  You type the latter in combination with the compose key to get the former.

Comment: Do you know of any other keyboards?  I find the Hacker's one confusing!  :-(

Comment: @verve - GAThrawn reports that the stock Android keyboard, [available on the Play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin), supports guillemets and access them via the method in [Al Everett's answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/48780/23562)

Comment: What "circle button" are you referring to? I only find a "dot in a circle" button, long pressing which opens the _Change keyboard_ dialog. The «» can be input by long-pressing any of the `"` or `<` buttons though.

Answer (score 1):

On my Galaxy S3, running 4.1.2, the stock keyboard has these characters. (I seem to be mistaken - see comments below.) When you bring up the numeric keyboard (from the 123 Sym button bottom-left), you will, above this same button, find what appears to be a one-third, which is not a fraction, but the indicator that you are on the first of three symbol keyboards. Click until you are on 2/3, and find your characters just above the space key.
An image of the specific keyboard(s) may be seen below:

[image: keyboards]
<sub>(source: [recombu.com](https://cdn.recombu.com/mobile/images/phones/1167/1338163097.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Do you mean these: 《》 ?

Comment: Those look really large when I use them in sentences.

Comment: Those appear to be "Mathematical [left/right] double angle bracket"s (Unicode U+27EA and U+27EB), not guillemets.

Comment: Fair enough. Didn't really know there were other sets of characters so close in composure.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be helpful, depending on how much Samsung has changed the keyboard, but I can get the guillemets this way:

- Press <kbd>?123</kbd> to get to the number/punctuation keyboard
- Long-press the <kbd>"</kbd> key to get a popup with non-English quotation marks: <kbd>„</kbd><kbd>“</kbd><kbd>”</kbd><kbd>«</kbd><kbd>»</kbd>

Comment: This doesn't appear to work in the Samsung keyboard on 4.1.2 on a Galaxy S3.  Long pressing on the quotation mark key just displays the quotation mark and nothing else.

Comment: Those extended quotationmarks are definitely available on the unmodified [Google Keyboard recently released on the Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin).

Comment: Well, as I said, I can't speak to whatever modifications Samsung may have done.